# Angular аккордион

Tags: angularjs

Есть рабочее меню аккордион:

```
<ul>
     <li  ng-repeat="li in list"><a ng-click="li.clicked=!li.clicked;" ng-href="{{li.link === '#' ? '':li.link}}"><i class="fa" ng-class="li.icon"></i> {{li.name}}<i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right" ng-show="li.submenu.length"></i></a>
        <ul class="childrenul" ng-class="{'show':li.clicked && li.submenu.length}">
            <li ng-repeat="subitem in li.submenu">{{subitem}}</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Но хотелось бы чтобы открывать можно было бы только одну вкладку, а сейчас открываются все. Как это можно реализовать в ng-repeat?

Comment: добавьте **в вопрос** пример `list`, и вообще контроллер. В идеале пример который можно запустить: либо тут в сниппете, либо на [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В контроллере:

```
$scope.openedIndex = 1;
$scope.openRoot = function(index) {
  $scope.openedIndex = index;
}
```

Во вьюхе.

```
<ul>
   <li  ng-repeat="li in list">
      <a ng-click="openRoot($index)" 
         ng-href="{{li.link === '#' ? '':li.link}}">
           <i class="fa" ng-class="li.icon"></i> 
           {{li.name}}
           <i class="pull-right fa fa-angle-right" ng-show="li.submenu.length"></i>
    </a>
           <ul class="childrenul" ng-class="{'show': openedIndex == $index && li.submenu.length}" ng-attr-id="{{li.id}}">
              <li ng-repeat="subitem in li.submenu">{{subitem}}</li>
           </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Описание:
Ты сохраняешь индекс выделенного элемента в меню. Пускай это будет элемент с индексом 1. ($index - индекс в ng-repeat на котором сейчас находится цикл).
Ты вешаешь событие клика `openRoot($index)` - т.е. передаешь в контроллер новый индекс нового выделенного элемента. Подменю смотрит openedIndex равен индексу подменю, если да, то открывает его.

Comment: функция особо не нужна

Comment: Я всегда такой функционал выношу в функции, мне не надо чтобы вьюха редактировала состояние, нет уж спасибо) Вьюха должна лишь сообщить что надо состояние поменять, а контроллер обработать новое состояние

Comment: нет смысла делать функцию для одной строки, которая не влияет ни на что внутри контроллера.

Comment: да я не про это.. ты меня не понимаешь совсем. Я просто говорю что так не правильно, и не надо прививать людей кто только учится писать, к плохому. Лучше покажи не "так работает", а "так работает правильно".

Comment: Правильно - чисто субъективное понятие.

Comment: Не буду больше отвечать, ты как то странно предрасположен к тому что я говорю, хоть оно и верно, даже не от моего лица, а от лица сообщества разработчиков (реально хороших разработчиков). Надо стараться брать только хорошее, либо стремиться к этому.

Comment: Пока не особо верно, от лица какого сообщества говоришь? с чего ты взял что они хорошие разработчики?

Comment: Я пожалуй закрою тему. Это стало не интересно)

Comment: А было интересно? :)

Comment: Ну да, очень даже) Просто я привожу доводы, а ты никак не реагируешь) Просто стоишь на своем. Хороший пример React+Redux, да и вообще об этом говори MVC модель, зачем придумали её? Чтобы разделить вид от контроллера и от модели.

Comment: Ты приводишь доводы и разряда: мне так сказали и я так думаю что это правда, поэтому это правда. Там еще и другие буквы есть типа MVP, MVVM, так что совсем не показатель.